# Weird Apache ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error

Tags: apache2, ssl

I bought a wildcard SSL cert from AlphaSSL but after installing it Firefox gives me `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error` when visiting the site.

I'm tearing my hair out I just trying to get this working.  Neither documentation, Google, nor the logs have been of much help:

/var/log/apache2/error.log

```
^[Fri Nov 01 04:39:04 2013] [error] [client 173.250.131.121] Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01
[Fri Nov 01 04:39:04 2013] [error] [client 173.250.131.121] Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01
```

/var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log

```
173.250.131.121 - - [01/Nov/2013:04:45:55 +0000] "\x16\x03" 501 311 "-" "-"
173.250.131.121 - - [01/Nov/2013:04:46:03 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 501 312 "-" "-"
```

I restarted Apache, I disabled other sites to ensure that V-Host I am configuring is the one that is getting loaded, checked that mod_ssl is loaded, and ran the certs through OpenSSL.  I've put a more complete terminal history in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/indolering/7261395).

Here is a compact version of my virtual host SSL settings.  Note that I've tried `46.149.28.113:443`, `_default_:443`, `*`, `secure.speech.is:443` and others.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost 46.149.28.113:443>
  ...
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/speech.is.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
      SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/AlphaSSLroot.crt
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Ideas?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Well, the DNS is running through Cloudflare but I "paused" Cloudflare and it's on a virtual host so it *shouldn't* be behind a reverse proxy....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what was wrong, I requested a new cert from CA using a non-encrypted private key.  However, upon install, it still didn't work so I started with a fresh copy of the default-SSL site and it started working.  It could be some weird interaction between Textmate and local file caches as (at one point) what I had open in Textmate and what was in my Nano shell differed but that could be bogus.  I also altered the filenames to remove the .is.crt but that shouldn't matter at all.

TL;DR Restarted from scratch using SSL template, did everything in the shell using Nano to bypass file caches, and exercised the demons by hopping on one foot.